# How to restore files that are there (hard drive size proves it) but not visible?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

There were some viruses on my laptop which got into my 500GB drive. All viruses cleaned but now the files are not visible. When I check the hard drive size it hasn't gone down but is the same as before.

Does this mean my files are still there? If so, how can they be retrieved.

Comment: did you at least try "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Show Hidden Files & Folders"?

Comment: What does "files are not visible" mean? Where are you looking and what exactly are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are Hidden, try to do something like [this](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-7/)

If they have been deleted, try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), however if that happened you should see freed space.

EDIT: according to the comment, the problem might lie elsewhere, maybe the virus messed around with the files and placed them somewhere else. Use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) or some other disk usage statistics viewer to enquire about where most space has gone to.

**EDIT + UPDATE:**

To restore hidden folders to their original state you should do the following. Note that I'm on a Portuguese version of Windows XP, but the core is there, it should be transversal to Windows 7 or 8, and I'll make it as easy to understand as possible:

Assuming that you have a mix of non-hidden and hidden folders like the following...

[image: Mix of regular and hidden folders]

...select them all, then press the right button on any folder, then go to `Properties`. You can do the same from the menu bar but this way it's easier.

[image: Accessing Properties]

A window like the following will appear. **Uncheck** the `Hidden` (in my version labeled `Oculto`) checkbox, then press `Apply`.

[image: File property window]

If you are doing this from a **NTFS** Partition (most likely, unless these files are on an external drive) another window will appear asking if you want to make this change to **ALL** files, even those included inside the folders and those inside the folders inside the folders and so on.
The main disadvantage in doing that is that some system files (namely `desktop.ini` and `thumbs.db` will from now on appear even if you have the "Show hidden files option" disabled). If this bothers you, check inside the hidden folders if the files inside them are also hidden. If they are, it is less bothersome to allow this, unless you want to do this over and over again.

[image: Subdirectory action spread]

Lastly, the end result is something like this. All files have become unhidden.

[image: All files are unhidden]

Comment: I did do the "show hidden files" thing before but there's no difference. The files seem "hidden" but in some other manner probably. The hard drive space has not free up so I suspect that the files are there. Any new files you put there, they are visible and usable. But ones before are not. You cannot see any folders even.

Comment: I used windirstat and could see all the folders/files. So I checked the folder options again and this time unticked the 3 'hide...' options. Here's a screenshot. http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6428/77v1.png And then the folders got visible like this: http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/7269/kfii.png Now, how do I restore them as normal folders?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: The hidden option in properties is greyed out. It cannot be clicked. What do I do now? http://i42.tinypic.com/904to1.png

Comment: I redirect you to [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/56005-file-folder-hide-unhide.html) post that explains how to do this from the command line. I might write something later (as I'm currently busy), to place it here on SU.

Comment: Maybe trying to use any of [these](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-enable-and-access-disabled-grayed-out-buttons-windows-and-checkboxes/) applications will be easier. From what I'm reading, this kind of behavior is caused by virus infection, as you pointed out initially.

Comment: Or yet [this](http://rajkishor09.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-enable-Show-Hidden-Files-and-Folders-option-disabled-after-virus-attack). Please say what method works for you.

Comment: Just before reading this my son found a method where you change the folder icon from properties and then the hidden gets to black from grey. That worked. But I'm keeping all these for future reference. Problem solved. Excellent help I got. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a [Linux LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_live_cd) and [investigate the filesystem](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Linux). This will avoid any permissions put in place by Windows and sidesteps any malware tricks.

- Check directory and file sizes using `du --si /path/to/folder`
- Find large files graphically using `gdmap`
- Recover deleted files with `photorec` (part of the testdisk package)

Recommendations for the LiveCD include: [Knoppix LiveCD](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html), [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), [Linux Mint LiveCD](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), etc.

Comment: Is there an equivalent windows only solution? I do not have access to linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your files may still be there.

When an operating system such as windows deletes a file, the file is not removed. Instead just the pointer to the file is removed. The operating system then considers the blocks where that file was located as free, and allows other programs to overwrite that data.

You can use a file recovery program to attempt to recover those files.

---

**Steps to recover Data**

1. Stop using the computer immediately ! (That includes going online, or installing any file recovery programs). If the files are important do not try and recover them yourself. It can actually do more harm. Take the drive to a data recovery specialist.
2. Take a snapshot of your current drive. Use a utility like [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) to create a clone of your hard drive. Always perform your first recovery attempts on the clone, not the actual drive.
3. Use a data recovery tool to scan for possible file fragments. The best that I have found are

   - RIPLinux (Recovery is possible), Is a bootable linux distro with a lot of recovery tools.
   - Data Rescue 3 (Mac), I've never had it not recover files from a working drive
   - Active@ (Windows), Worked for me when every other program failed.
   - BartPE - A windows disk that has a lot of good diagnostic & recovery tools
4. If a program recovers files, do not recover them directly to the drive where they were lost, it can actually overwrite itself. Save the files to a different drive.

---

[15 free file recovery programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm)
[inodes on linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)
[How to recover deleted files](http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software)

Comment: Remember that the poster said the space was seemingly occupied, so the chances are that the files are still there; otherwise the harddrive would reflect that free space had become available.

Comment: yes that's true. I don't think they are deleted just not accessible for some reason. when the virus first got in, the folders had changed their icons from the usual win 7 ones to application type icons. So the folder name would be xxxx.exe rather than just xxxx. now after the antivirus scan these are gone but the HD space remains the same.